# Why does javamail API have an array of senders for messages?

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

i need to use some sort of a port to javaMail (link [here](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) ) that takes messages from an email server (gmail in my case, but might change in the future) , and reads some information from them.

one of the things i've noticed in the API is that getFrom method returns an array of Address objects , as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#getFrom%28%29) .

my question is : in which cases would this method return :

1. null
2. empty array
3. more than 1 sender

?

all of my emails always had exactly one sender , no matter how weird it was sent (CC,BCC,forward,...) .

they say there "In certain implementations, this may be different from the entity that actually sent the message." , so how could i know for sure who sent the message, and if the current implementation is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frist two are DIRECTLY from the api:

(This attribute = the 'from' attribute of the email in question)

1) `This method returns null if this attribute is not present in this message.`

2) `Returns an empty array if this attribute is present, but contains no addresses.`

3) It checks the 'from' field of the email and returns an array of Address objects with one Address per 
   entity found in that field.  So, it will return an array of size > 1 when there is more than one 'sender' listed

Comment: how could it be that there are no senders? what's the difference between #1 and #2 ? i still don't get in which cases there would be more than one sender or 0 . is it just a matter of the email server ? can you think of any scenario that such weird scenarios will occur ?

Comment: It could be that a system generated email is badly formed and leaves out the from field or possibly adds the field but doesn't add any sender value to it.  It is one of those things that is unlikely but possible.

Comment: There's no authentication of any of the content of an email message unless the message has been signed and you verify the signature.  Otherwise, the message can contain anything, true or false, and should be careful what you trust.  That's why 98% of all email is spam.

Comment: so , even though it doesn't make any sense , they have it this way since you can't guarantee the data is ok?